# What's the best network simulator for educational purpose?

Tags: networking, simulation, simulator

What's the best network simulator for educational purpose?

I want to use it to help students learn the basic network concepts, such as LAN, WAN, IP addressing, network layers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Network event simulator,
[ns-2](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/) is the one. You can have a look at the example programs in ns-2 directory to illustrate basic ideas.

For demonstration of Wireless **LAN,Wifi, WiMax** and other networks simulation, you can make use of [contributed page](http://nsnam.isi.edu/nsnam/index.php/Contributed_Code) by other researchers and educational institutions.

[ns-3](http://www.nsnam.org) is the successor to ns-2.  It supports newer technologies such as IPv6, WiMAX, and LTE, and is under active development. It is also in use as [courseware](http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/index.php/Education)